# UIActivityViewController UIActivityTypeMail ruining my mail urls

Tags: html, ios, cocoa-touch, base64, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am trying to send an email from my app. I format the email in a custom ActivityProviderMessage along the lines of this:

```
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body>This is my html email body and
here is a very long url link: <a href=\"%@\">Long url link</a></body></html>", _url];
```

The problem with this, is when I receive the email and take a look at the source, the url is screwed up because it has been put on multiple lines with lots of = inserted at the end of each line.
The URL is actually a Base64 encoded image, which when pasted into safari shows the image fine.

Here's an example of a small image url, paste it into safari and you'll see the image:

> data:image/png;base64,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

Now when I log the message returned from my ActivityProviderMessage method it looks like this, which works as it should (Paste into a .html and open it, the link shows the image):

```
<html><body>This is my html email body and here is a very long url link: <a href='data:image/png;base64,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'>Long url link</a></body></html>
```

However the received email source in mail.app looks like this:

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv=3D"content-type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3D= utf-8"></head><body dir=3D"auto"><div>This is my html email body and here is=  a very long url link: <a href=3D"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE= UgAAAB4AAAAeCAYAAAA7MK6iAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAA= AyRpVFh0WE1MOmNvbS5hZG9iZS54bXAAAAAAADw/eHBhY2tldCBiZWdpbj0i77u/IiBpZD0iVzVN= ME1wQ2VoaUh6cmVTek5UY3prYzlkIj8+IDx4OnhtcG1ldGEgeG1sbnM6eD0iYWRvYmU6bnM6bWV0= YS8iIHg6eG1wdGs9IkFkb2JlIFhNUCBDb3JlIDUuMy1jMDExIDY2LjE0NTY2MSwgMjAxMi8wMi8w= Ni0xNDo1NjoyNyAgICAgICAgIj4gPHJkZjpSREYgeG1sbnM6cmRmPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9y= Zy8xOTk5LzAyLzIyLXJkZi1zeW50YXgtbnMjIj4gPHJkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbiByZGY6YWJvdXQ9= IiIgeG1sbnM6eG1wPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvIiB4bWxuczp4bXBNTT0i= aHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS94YXAvMS4wL21tLyIgeG1sbnM6c3RSZWY9Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5h= ZG9iZS5jb20veGFwLzEuMC9zVHlwZS9SZXNvdXJjZVJlZiMiIHhtcDpDcmVhdG9yVG9vbD0iQWRv= YmUgUGhvdG9zaG9wIENTNiAoTWFjaW50b3NoKSIgeG1wTU06SW5zdGFuY2VJRD0ieG1wLmlpZDox= MTFGOTk4Q0NGNzIxMUUyOUY1REQxQkQ4NDFFMzEwMCIgeG1wTU06RG9jdW1lbnRJRD0ieG1wLmRp= ZDoxMTFGOTk4RENGNzIxMUUyOUY1REQxQkQ4NDFFMzEwMCI+IDx4bXBNTTpEZXJpdmVkRnJvbSBz= dFJlZjppbnN0YW5jZUlEPSJ4bXAuaWlkOjExMUY5OThBQ0Y3MjExRTI5RjVERDFCRDg0MUUzMTAw= IiBzdFJlZjpkb2N1bWVudElEPSJ4bXAuZGlkOjExMUY5OThCQ0Y3MjExRTI5RjVERDFCRDg0MUUz= MTAwIi8+IDwvcmRmOkRlc2NyaXB0aW9uPiA8L3JkZjpSREY+IDwveDp4bXBtZXRhPiA8P3hwYWNr= ZXQgZW5kPSJyIj8+R9i41AAAAedJREFUeNq8l81Kw0AQx9NQPHupoAhttVqw2oqePPkK3n0DT55s= K1ZBq1a9+CIefADPnvyoVfEzVVAQwZMoFEGchQ2Mf3aTTdp04E93N7P5JbszO2kssfZjRWAOKU0a= JL2qHOwIocJeSCPdAN8yqGt3pGyU4AZpVHPthjQUBficNO7j80ga6CT4ilQw9BWBlhCNeJvQJ1Iy= 4Jx3Up/dZvRy6FuAuWdhwU2I3gqpX/762YPI7zBgMTEF0KpsV33gDTev7RCBNMz6RQa1GLyomHtB= yoeJ6jppjPXLpF3DudcY+abgf09LViLVNL4rpB3I3xw6maTTPSnD+kukPQ/oBqRbRuUYN4jeFLyp= DroM0CYek6ZL7QAUl9CCINtk/WcvqBfYgTxdhRsjtAaBlPLbP9ugtOES4p7WIPJzJtFq+5Q2sWTb= mrkleKBL0qRpbiIYS1tS5itaGR5IFPuJICcRBy9ofLbgGKzIMR692aDnbhwCyLUp0gHb63XSL2sb= pYyXxeRXZg+pxcc1eYy1OB22ptqKvZ1nbXHjY02FCg3lS32iKOizshLNKCI/3+73kgD3wpiIziOP= YlGwOmBiqb9hbF/h90Fa7BTUfeOWx/U50mEU/3FU1WmadGpFbAL8KY9J8ftldcn+BBgAl0Jc3zM1= awwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=3D">Long url link</a></div><div><br><br>Sent from my iPh= one</div></body></html>=
```

I notice that the received email automatically has a new Head tag in it, even if I supply my own in the email:

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv=3D"content-type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3D= utf-8"></head>
```

So, to get this working, is it simply a case of finding a right format for the url?
Or perhaps I need extra fields when I generate the email to tell mail.app not to change anything?

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to send an email with an attachment, then use this method:

```
- (void)addAttachmentData:(NSData*)attachment mimeType:(NSString*)mimeType fileName:(NSString*)filename
```

Otherwise, if your goal is to show an embedded image inline in the message, then you should use a standard `<img>` tag in the body of your email with a `url` that points to an image already publicly available online.

Comment: My overall goal is to have a link in the email that opens my app with the image, by using the url myappscheme://image?url=<THE ENCODED IMAGE DATA> but the image url data keeps being split up. I don't really want to have to host the image somewhere first.

Comment: I wonder, would it be possible if I add the image as an attachment, to get a reference to it in a url within the email content? (Like showing it in line)

Comment: What's doing the splitting-up of the image data? Have you tried sending the same starting text from different clients (web/iOS/desktop) and from different providers (Gmail/Yahoo) etc?

Comment: It may be an unsolvable problem if you can't control the way the image data is sent. Also, email providers often strip away all <html>, <body>, and <head> tags for safety reasons. There aren't any gaurantees, only a best-practice recommendation to code your emails like it's 1995 and use nested tables. :-)

Comment: It's hard to tell where it's being broken up, however as the received email link is broken when viewed on both OSX Mail and iOS Mail, I assume it's broken as it's sent by iOS. Maybe there is a better way to format it so it doesn't get broken up.

Comment: I've just got this working :-) I created a link with my url `appscheme://image?url=<THE_ENCODED_IMAGE>` and the link wasn't broken up :-) Maybe mail just thought it was plain text while it didn't have a `...://` before it.
I will award you the bounty for helping me. Could you please take a look at my other question where I want to share this url on twitter and facebook too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627897/ios-tweet-image-can-i-get-the-image-url-before-upload

Comment: Hooray. Hopefully I helped somewhat. :-)