# iOS tweet image - Can I get the image url before upload?

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, image-uploading, url-scheme

I want to be able to share images from my app on twitter/facebook/email etc..
There's probably hundreds of different ways to do this which is quite simple.
However what I need/want to do, is allow the images to be opened by other people straight into my app (If they have it installed).

So I have a url scheme so a url will open my app with an image like this:

```
myurlscheme://image?url=http://imageurl.com
```

The problem I have, is the process for uploading the image, but adding my url scheme to the beginning of the url.

If I could know the url twitter/facebook is going to use before I send the tweet, I could add my url scheme to the front of the image url and put it in the tweet. I'm guessing this might not be possible though.

Another thought is to upload the image to another service, get the url, then compose and send the tweet. Are there any suitable services for doing this? (Preferably free services) I dont really want to have to host the images myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1) I don't see how you plan on conjuring an image URL before you upload the image - that is a chicken/egg situation. I would recommend taking a look at an actual image URL after you upload it to facebook, twitter, etc and try to figure out even one character of what it would be for the next image you upload. Regarding twitter specifically the image URL is also going to vary depending on what upload service is being used.

2) regarding uploading the image and getting the URL why not look into tapping into the [flickr API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/)?

Comment: Thanks. 1, I was hoping there might be an upload service that can sort of pre-book a url then take the image. I guess not.
2, Thanks, I'll take a look at that.
Today i've been looking at custom URL shortener scripts, and I might be able to use one to shorten a Base64 data image url and use that.

Comment: 1) That's a hell of a venture idea ;)  2) also a decent idea. if you own the shortener hash then you control what your URL iteration looks like.